# iOS framework to get audio in from dock connector

Tags: iphone, frameworks, audio, ios

How would I go abouts playing an 'audio in' through the dock connector in an iOS app? I'm making an app just for myself and have no plans of putting it into the apple store. I have the 30pin breakout board, and on it there are pins for L/R audio in, but I can not find any info on how to use them?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Any info or direction of any kind will be helpful. I can not seem to find anything so far, and it has to be possible, otherwise those pins wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, your only officially supported option for any accessory using the dock connector would be to use the [External Accessory Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html), which requires enrollment in the [Made for iPod Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) (overkill for your purposes). However, the iPhone and iPod both support line-in via the headphone jack, and there are plenty of apps that make use of audio input. At least it provides some possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the pinouts for the dock connector [floating about](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml)? It appears that certain resistances connected to pin 21 indicate to the iDevice what is connected.

68kΩ seems to be the magic number for audio in/out.